# How to implement subList into a JSONArray

Tags: java, android

I have been using it with ArrayList but now my entire code changed to JSONArray and I cannot use subList anymore, I was thinking on transform my current JSONArray to an arraylist in order to use, but I don't know if there is a similar method for JSONArray, I have checked an example and there is using subList, but for me it is not working.

```
public JSONArray getList(int qty) {

        if (qty > orderedArray.length())
            qty = orderedArray.length();

        return orderedArray.subList(0, qty); //not working for me
    }
```

I have seen [this](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/javax.json.JsonArray/subList) example and is using subList with JSONArray, any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your JSONArray to List and use sublist.

```
List listdata= new ArrayList();
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){ 
    listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
   }
```

now use `listData` as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a utility class for converting your JsonArray to ArrayList, and use the sublist method in a clean way.

here is how the class would look like.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class ArrayUtil {


   public static ArrayList<Object> toArrayList(JSONArray jArr)
   {
      ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
      try {
         for (int i=0, i < jArr.length(); i++){
            list.add(jArr.get(i));
         }
      } catch ( JSONException e) {}

      return list;
   }

   public static JSONArray subJsonArray( JSONArray originalJsonArray, int fromIndex, int toIndex ) {

      ArrayList<Object> list = toArrayList( originalJsonArray );
      list.subList( fromIndex, toIndex );

      return new JSONArray( list );
   }
}
```